# What is the difference between = and empty and ~ in location?

Tags: nginx

What is the difference between = and empty and ~  in location?

```
location  /css/ { 
}
location = /css/ {
}
location ~ /css/ {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With no modifier, it's a prefix string.

> A location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular expression.

With the `~` modifier, it's a case-sensitive regex.

> Regular expressions are specified with the preceding “~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or the “~” modifier (for case-sensitive matching).

With the `=` modifier, it's an exact match.

> using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates.

Quotes are from [the manual](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).